# GraphView library x and y axis

Tags: java, android, graph

I am using a `GraphView` library and i want to use the method `GraphViewData` to show the `LineGraph`. To be honest I don't know how to generate the `LineGraph` with this library. So I removed the sample mock data that shows the `LineGraph` and replaced it with my own x data and y data.

But I am doing something wrong, it does not shows the line it self, only it fills the x axis and y axis:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras != null) {
    valueX = extras.getDouble("xValue");
    valueY = extras.getDouble("yValue");
    Log.d("X = " + valueX, " Y = " + valueY);
}

GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(
    new GraphViewData[] {
        new GraphViewData(valueX, valueY)
    });

// graph with dynamically genereated horizontal and vertical labels
GraphView graphView;
graphView = new LineGraphView(
    this,                         // context
    "Incomming Bluetooth Data");  // heading
graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
layout.addView(graphView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You only define the coordinates for one point.
To draw your line, you need to define the coordonates for 2 different points.

Add another GraphViewData in the array with different X and Y values.